# sum the decimal number in list. python

Tags: python, sum

i wass trying to print the Training result, However, the test accuracy can not be sumed.

```
q=(['0.50000', '0.56250', '0.50000', '0.50000'])

sum(q)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Remove `'` from numbers

Comment: either sum strings `sum(q,"")` or sum numbers `sum(float(v) for v in q)`

Comment: @JanStránský Did `sum(q,"")` really work for you?

Comment: @superbrain you got me again. I am using `sum` with some `Vector` instances as `sum(vectors,zeroVector)`, expected the same behavior for all able to be summed..

Answer (score 5):

You have a list of `str` so first you have to convert them to `float`, which you can do using a generator expression within `sum`.

```
>>> sum(float(i) for i in q)
2.0625
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone should post the imho proper version (see comments below):

```
>>> sum(map(float, q))
2.0625
```

Comment: Declaring that `map` is the "proper" version over a generator expression is somewhere between tenuous and flat-out wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: @CoryKramer Well imho, reimplementing a built-in isn't a proper thing to do. Not sure what that very old answer about a different case and rather agreeing with me is supposed to tell me?

Comment: @CoryKramer Can you please enlighten me about what that answer is supposed to tell me and how I'm between tenuous and flat-out wrong?

Comment: Well I guess that depends on why your version is "proper" in the first place. If it is related to performance, `map` vs generator expressions are essentially equal in speed depending on the use-case. If it about style, most (?) python developers consider generator expressions "more pythonic".  At the end of the day, it really doesn't matter and is up to each developer which they prefer. And since it is indeed a preference at that point, neither solution is more "proper" than the other.

Comment: @CoryKramer Like I said, I don't find it proper to reimplement a built-in that Python already provides. And I wouldn't call the speed "essentially equal". I tested our solutions on lists from 0 to 1,000,000 elements, mine was consistently faster by about factor 1.23. Where do I find statistics about how many Python developers consider that generator expression solution more pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

`sum` function uses default `start` value as `0`.

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, /, start=0)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
```

So adding a `int` object with a `str`ing object will raise `TypeError`.

```
>>> 0 + '0.50000'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

In order to fix this, you can convert the string object into float object first and then apply the `sum` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
q=(['0.50000', '0.56250', '0.50000', '0.50000'])
result = 0 # create a variable wich will store the value.

for i in q: # loop over your elements
    result += float(i) # cast your temp variable (i) to float and add each element to result. 
print(result) # escape the loop and print the result variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q=([0.50000, 0.56250, 0.50000, 0.50000])
sum(q)
```

or

```
q=(['0.50000', '0.56250', '0.50000', '0.50000'])
sum([float(x) for x in q])
```

Comment: Explaining what, exactly, was wrong with the question and how your answer solves the problem would be important.